# Profile pictures in web app - best practice of implementing

Tags: node.js, image, express, socket.io, avatar

I want to implement profile pictures (avatars) as simple and safe as possible, i'm using `express`+`passport`+`mongoose`+`socket.io`, all the latest versions.
As I have no experience with such functionality, and after few hours of intense googling, i still have no solid idea where to start and how to make it cosy and simple, yet safe.

The question is about how one implement user's usage of avatars in web app, via file uploads, or via something like gravatar, i really need an advise on where to start

Answer (score 0):

express + passport + mongoose, seems to be a good option.

First you need to persist the data somewhere, that's where MongoDB is useful. With Mongoose ODM you can create your models to perform easily CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations.

Then you need a server that comunicates with the client and the database. Express is a Node.js framework that makes really easy to set your session, routes, etc.

The users gotta authenticate before avatar is send, so Passport is a library that helps and it can be easily set up with express.

Socket.io, is a node module that creates a persistent connection with client so they can comunicate in "real-time". I don't think it will help much to your project unless you're planning that the avatar image change in real-time when updated.

I suggest you start by setting up your Express and the authentication with Passport

Comment: All things are done, i mean its an indev app with  express mongoose and sockets, i just don't know where to start with implementing profile pictures into this, for the moment i can see that gravatar is pretty one-button simple option, yet still not decided

Comment: You probably got a "Edit profile" view. So when the user selects a image to upload and then saves their profile, an express controller should listen to the uploading file so you can save it in Mongo so next time it shows the new avatar

Comment: I understand it, and that a pretty vague cocncept, im interested in exact practice of uploading a file and making it safe from possible hdd flooding attacks on server, which modules, how, or is it better just to get off with gravatar and stop making life harder